# what's the Naturalness of image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python-3.6

How to compute the naturalness of image with python?

Naturalness is the degree of correspondence between images and human perception of reality. Huang et al. [15] proposed an approach to obtain a quantitative description of naturalness by grouping the pixels with 20L80 and S>0.1 in HSL color space according to their hue (H coordinate) value into three sets: Skin, Grass and Sky. The naturalness score (https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~johnm/courses/mathdm/talks/dimitri-clickadvert.pdf)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looking at that paper, reading an image into OpenCV, translating it to HSL, then using `numpy` routines would soon give an answer. Have a go, then post the code and we can help you.

Comment: ok  I got it, I will update my question